# Specifying Context menu with specific options - merge

Tags: handsontable

I'm using Handsontable v0.22 with the merge functionality. I want to customize the context menu to remove some features, but when I look at the docs for this, the merge menu option doesn't exists.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.22.0/demo-context-menu.html#page-specific

If I try with the following, I just get a menu option named "merge_cells" which of course doesn't work to merge with.

contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'merge_cells'],

Any tips?

Brgds

Jonas

Comment: have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `mergeCells` option to be `true` while initializing the handsontable. Merge Cells option will automatically appear in the context menu.

Comment: Hi, but the problem is that when you want to customize the menu you need to specifically know the names of all the menu choices, and the documentation doesn't specify the name for the merge menu choice.